# Inserting a C# record into a table with multiple foreign keys in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I have a `Players` table, a `Teams` table, and a `TeamPlayers` table. I want to assign a player that's not in the `TeamPlayers` table to a team that already is. I have a drop down list that shows the teams that are in the `TeamPlayers` table and a drop down list that shows the players that aren't in the `TeamPlayers` table.

This is the `TeamPlayers` table's structure:

```
CREATE TABLE TTeamPlayers
(
     intTeamPlayerID INTEGER NOT NULL,
     intTeamID       INTEGER NOT NULL,
     intPlayerID     INTEGER NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT TTeamPlayers_PK PRIMARY KEY (intTeamPlayerID)
)
```

Inside my submit button I will have code that will take the `Player` that's unassigned and add him/her to the `TeamPlayers` table. I'm not quite sure how to do this I'm a student trying to learn ahead of the class and am unsure I'm using C# to do this. Can Anyone help. Below is the code for the dropdownlists

```
private void PopulateDropDowns()
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=itd2");

        // Select Query.
        string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM vPlayersThatsUnassigned";

        // Providing information to SQL command object about which query to 
        // execute and from where to get database connection information.
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);

        //To check current state of the connection object. If it is closed open the connection
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        //ddlAgeGroup.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ddlPlayers.DataTextField = "Players";
        ddlPlayers.DataValueField = "intPlayerID";
        ddlPlayers.DataBind();

        con.Close();

        ddlPlayers.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select an A Player--", "0"))
}

private void PopulateTeams()
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=itd2");

        // Select Query.
        string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM vTeamsAssigned";

        // Providing information to SQL command object about which query to 
        // execute and from where to get database connection information.
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);

        //To check current state of the connection object. If it is closed open the connection
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        ddlTeams.DataTextField = "strTeam";
        ddlTeams.DataValueField = "intTeamID";
        ddlTeams.DataBind();

        con.Close();

        ddlTeams.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select A Team --", "0"));
    }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] with us.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear if you are you looking for exact sql to do this or just an explanation of how to do it.

In these types of situations when you need a list of Assigned/Unassigned i will have 2 sql methods that will take the TeamID and return those people.

I assume you have 3 tables something along the lines of this... Players, Teams, PlayerTeams (many to many).  PlayerTeams will only have a playerid and a teamid.  You will need to pass the teamid as a parameter via the @teamid to each call.

So, a typical sql for those that are Assigned would look something like this...

```
Select * from Players p inner join PlayerTeams pt on pt.playerid = p.playerid where pt.teamid = @teamid
```

Now,  to get the players that are not on the team is a little bit more.

```
Select * from Players where playerid not in (select playerid from playerteams where teamid = @teamid)
```

Then to add someone you just do the insert into the playerteam table

```
Insert into playerteams (playerid, teamid) values (@playerid, @teamid)
```

If you need a little more code on how to make SQL calls well this is easily found on here so i wont go into that.

Answer (score 0):

To select players not in PlayerTeams:

```
select p.*
from Players p
left join TeamPlayers tp on p.intPlayerID = tp.intPlayerID 
Where tp.intPlayerID  is null /*there is no record in TeamPlayers */
```

To select teams that are in the TeamPlayers  table:

```
select t.*
from Teams t
left join TeamPlayers tp on p.intTeamID = tp.intTeamID
```

And when you process the submit event, you get intPlayerID and intTeamID and insert the values